# Why is there an aggregate in this UPDATE plan?

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, update

Given this

```
declare @Data table (id int, fact char(1));
declare @Summary table (id int, collected varchar(99));

insert @Data(id, fact)
values
    (1, 'a'),
    (1, 'b'),
    (2, 'c'),
    (2, 'd'),
    (2, 'e');

-- Form a list of unique id values
insert @Summary(id, collected) select distinct id, '' from @Data;

-- Accumulate the fact values into collected
update s
set collected = collected + d.fact
from @Summary as s
inner join @Data as d
    on d.id = s.id;

select * from @Summary;
```

I had expected

```
id   collected
---  ---------
1    ab
2    cde
```

However what I get is

```
id   collected
---  ---------
1    a
2    c
```

The first `fact` per `id` is written and the others skipped. The reason is obvious from the plan

[image]

where the Stream Aggregate passes through the first row per `id`; 5 rows are passed to it from the Nested Loop and it passes 2 rows to the Compute Scalar.

The result and general plan shape is the same with and without primary keys. Changing to temp tables, or real tables makes no difference. I can reproduce on SQL Server 2017 and 2019.

My question is what is the theoretical basis for inserting the aggregate into the plan? My best guess is it is a form of Halloween protection. I understood its purpose was to prevent a row leapfrogging ahead of the current scan position and hence being updated a second time. I can sort-of see that applying here as a row in @Summary would be touched many times in the absence of the aggregate. It seems a very expansive application of Halloween protection, though.

I know there are ways to achieve this - STRING_AGG being the most obvious. My real use-case is around constructing JSON. This is just a minimal reproducible example. My specific question here is about understanding the semantics and behaviour of the optimizer.

Comment: `MERGE` would raise an error rather than attempt to update the same row more than once or pick an arbitrary one. Postgres warns [a target row shouldn't join to more than one row from the other table(s). If it does, then only one of the join rows will be used to update the target row, but which one will be used is not readily predictable.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-update.html)

Comment: SQL Server gives the same error for MERGE (it was one of the work-arounds I tried, and failed, to get working).

Comment: To be clear I was referring to `MERGE` in SQL Server. The comparison with Postgres was just on the `UPDATE` behaviour, AFAIK Postgres doesn't implement `MERGE`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't Halloween protection, it's normal `UPDATE` semantics.

Check out this warning from [the docs on UPDATE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#best-practices):

> The results of an UPDATE statement are undefined if the statement includes a FROM clause that is not specified in such a way that only one value is available for each column occurrence that is updated, that is if the UPDATE statement is not deterministic.

A `SET` statement doesn't accumulate like you expect it to* - it just updates each qualifying row in the Summary table once.

Since the join results in duplicate potential values for collected, the optimizer introduced a Stream Aggregate - essentially it groups by the "primary key" of the heap (the row locator, referred to as `Bmk1000` in the execution plan) to get just one value for `collected` in each row.

Looking at the plan XML, you can see that the internal only ["ANY" aggregate](https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/07/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.html) was used to choose among the possible values of collected and fact:

```xml
<ScalarOperator ScalarString="ANY(@Summary.[collected] as [s].[collected])">
  <Aggregate AggType="ANY" Distinct="false">
    <ScalarOperator>
      <Identifier>
        <ColumnReference Table="@Summary" Alias="[s]" Column="collected" />
      </Identifier>
    </ScalarOperator>
  </Aggregate>
</ScalarOperator>
```

*this sort of accumulation does work when you add a variable assignment into the mix, although it's still not "supported."  This is referred to as "quirky updates" ([reference](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/running-totals))

Comment: @MichaelGreen "*...I'm trying to understand why it must be made to work this way*" - I don't know if there is a satisfying answer to that question other than this is the documented way that update works.  Qualifying rows in the table to be updated are only updated once - and if there are multiple potential values / expressions to choose from, the optimized chooses one and silently discards the rest.

Comment: @JoshDarnell no worries! I realise it's a bit of an "angels on a pinhead" question. It got me thinking, however. And that's why I spend time here.

Answer (score 2):

Josh's answer (thanks Josh!) got me thinking about determinism.

I can see for the fundamental usage `update table set column = value`, when there are duplicate source rows, the question must be answered which matching value from the source will be written to the destination. The simplest implementation would be to let the iterators run to completion. Whichever row the storage engine happens to pass to the query last is the value written to the target table. Since there is no inherent order in a table which row is last is indeterminate.

Given that indeterminism the optimizer is free to choose any row it likes. The semantics of the statement are satisfied whether the first, last or any intermediate row is applied. Given that, it makes sense to choose the first row and avoid the redundant work of itterating over subsequent rows. This is a performance optimization, however, not a constraint on the semantics of an update nor does it exist to ensure the correctness of the result.

Moving on to my example, I can see how the optimizer detects the same shape (update with multiple matching source values) and applies the performance optimization. This is just how Microsoft have specified their implementation of the update statement. There is nothing fundamental to the relational model which means it must be so.

I suppose there is an alternate implementation whereby the optimizer recognizes there are multiple matching rows and also that there is an aggregate being performed (`set column = column + value`). Then it will execute the aggregation rather than injecting the performance optimization of the Stream Aggregate (ANY) which eliminates duplicates. Of course this would be a change to the spec of a TSQL update. I don't imagine there would be value to MS to implement such a change since the behaviour is available through other constructs.